# Identify Xpath in a dynamic table using xpath axes

Tags: selenium, xpath

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfEfO.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTCAY.jpg)I want to write an xpath using axes for the a column value in the table, corresponding to a particular value in the same row.

e.g. I want to print last column value for HDIL.

Xpath that i have tried :

```
//a[contains (text(), ‘HDIL’)]/following-sibling::td[@class=‘green’]
```

HTML

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://demo.guru99.com/">
                    HDIL                    </a>
                </td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>564.6</td>
                    <td>68.8</td>
                <td><font class="green">+   6.1</font></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Please supply a snippet of  the table and your code

Comment: Somehow I couldn’t attach . I need 10 reputation to add that. Will copy the HTML here.

Answer (score 0):

You may find 'table row' with text = 'HDIL' and from this row get the last table cell. E.g. like this:

```
//tr[td[contains(string(), 'HDIL')]]/td[last()]
```

or

```
//tr[td[contains(string(), 'HDIL')]]/td[font]
```

Or using webDriver I would find all cells for needed row and get the last one:

```
// C# code;
var lastCell = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[td[contains(string(), 'HDIL')]]/td")).Last();
```

Comment: Didn't work , last column is the sibling of the first column unlike the other values who are the child. i have added HTML please refer and suggest a solution. TIA

Comment: Hey that actually works. But why didn’t it worked when i used //a[contains(string(),’HDIL’)]/td[font]

Comment: Though if i skip td[font] , hdil value is found

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is written in the way of taking siblings from `a` but you should take siblings of `td` that contains `a`. Your xpath also implies that `class='green'` is the attribute of `td` but in fact (according to your example) it is the attribute of `font` that is child of `td`.

So the proper xpath would be: `//td[a[contains (text(), 'HDIL')]]/following-sibling::td[font[@class='green']]`.

See test [here](http://xpather.com/htmh4TJO).

Comment: hey thanks , but what if that's not a last column ? in that case I wanted to use path axes.

Comment: What do you mean? What should be the output in my example?

Comment: I meant,  what if it was not the last column i want to print . May be a third with respect to HDIL. So what we will use?

Comment: I see.. Try this `//td[a[contains (text(), ‘HDIL’)]]/following-sibling::td[@class=‘green’]` your query did not work because you query siblings of `a` but you need to take siblings of `td` that contains `a`